# unidentified datatype in external header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, include

I am attempting to write a .dll using a library that comes with some demo projects that run with no issues. When I attempt to #include a header, the compiler complains that certain datatypes are not defined. here is a sample of the errors generated

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.1.4 build 4260\sdk\include\ak\wwise\utilities.h(82) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCWSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.1.4 build 4260\sdk\include\ak\wwise\utilities.h(90) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCWSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.1.4 build 4260\sdk\include\ak\wwise\utilities.h(97) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCWSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.1.4 build 4260\sdk\include\ak\wwise\utilities.h(107) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCWSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.1.4 build 4260\sdk\include\ak\wwise\utilities.h(110) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DWORD'
1>c:\program files (x86)\audiokinetic\wwise v2012.1.4 build 4260\sdk\include\ak\wwise\utilities.h(113) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DWORD'
```

adding

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
```

to this external utilities.h file solves the problem, but as its a 3rd party header I don't believe I should be editing it, and considering these other demo projects #include the same header as I am, it seems to suggest that the problem lies elsewhere.

Can anyone think of a reason why this could be happening. The library I'm trying to use is Wwise (a sound engine). Here is a list of .libs im linking

```
AkSoundEngine.lib
AkMemoryMgr.lib
AkStreamMgr.lib
AkMusicEngine.lib
CommunicationCentral.lib
dxguid.lib
ws2_32.lib
dsound.lib
dinput8.lib
xinput.lib
```

Comment: Have you tried `#include <windows.h>` _before_ including the third party headers?

Comment: i just did and it solved it, thanks.

Comment: Great, I'll put it in an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is solved by changing the order your headers are included.

Assuming a file called `header.h` has the following:

```
LPCWSTR foo;
```

In you main:

```
// This is fail.
#include "header.h"
#include <windows.h>
```

Try:

```
// Success!
#include <windows.h>
#include "header.h"
```

Comment: Given that the header in question comes from a third party, yes, this is typically how to solve the problem. The **real** solution, of course, is to write headers that stand on their own.